# What does nda ンだ stand for?

Tags: translation, meaning, manga, anime

[image]

I know that kore means “this” but i didn’t understand what does this sentence/word means i also didn’t know what is the meaning of nda

Comment: Probably a shortened version of なんだ. so "what is this?" Also, I heard んだ from old people a lot when I lived in sendai - meant "yep" like そうだ

Answer (score 4):

@chargestriker is correct, it's a shortened form of なんだ, so the whole sentence would be なんだこれ？ or なんだ、これは？ ... essentially "What's this?" or colloquially "What the heck is this?"  ...we do the same in English, with many people shortening the question to "The heck is this??"